# How to set bucket policy using AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

getting exception while setting bucket policy through Java SDK :
Statement is missing required element (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy

Bucket policy :

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"Policy1610615475618",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"Stmt1610615465140",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Principal":"*",
         "Action":"s3:PutObject",
         "NotResource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::pwn-bkt/*.PNG",
            "arn:aws:s3:::pwn-bkt/*.JPG"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The policy is fine. Please double check that the code you've posted in SO correctly represents your real bucket policy.

Comment: the same policy works fine if I use Resource in place of NotResource. I guess Resource attribute is required to create Policy Object in AWS  java SDK.